# Code execution order for listeners

Tags: java, gwt, listener, vaadin, onclicklistener

I've narrowed my problem down to this simple code snippet:

```
    this.addClickListener(new ClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

            Label spinner = new Label();
            spinner.addStyleName("spinner");

            ((HorizontalLayout) event.getButton().getParent()).replaceComponent(event.getButton(), spinner);

        }

    });
```

What it does is creating a loading indicator and replacing the clicked button with it accordingly:

1. [image: Button]
2. *CLICK* =)
3. [image: Spinning]

Okay, let's (again, simplified of course) execute another listener by adding the line `getSaveListener().saveClick();`. Overall the code looks like this:

```
    this.addClickListener(new ClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

            Label spinner = new Label();
            spinner.addStyleName("spinner");

            ((HorizontalLayout) event.getButton().getParent()).replaceComponent(event.getButton(), spinner);

            getSaveListener().saveClick();

        }

    });
```

The "SaveListener" is setup like this:

```
    bu.addSaveClickListener(new SaveClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void saveClick() {

            System.out.println("Yes1");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Yes2");

        }

    });
```

The desired behavior is that the button changes into the spinner, writes "Yes1", waits 4 seconds and finally writes "Yes2".

1. [image: Button]
2. *CLICK* =)
3. [image: Spinning]
4. "Yes1"
5. "Waiting"
6. "Yes2"

The problem is that it does the "saveClick" stuff *before* the spinner stuff:

1. [image: Button]
2. *CLICK* =)
3. "Yes1"
4. "Waiting"
5. "Yes2"
6. [image: Spinning]

Why is the "SaveListener" (`.saveClick()`) executed before the "ClickListener" (`.buttonClick()`)? How can I correct this?

---

### Additional test:

```
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

            Label spinner = new Label();
            spinner.addStyleName("spinner");

            System.out.println("SPINNER!");
            ((HorizontalLayout) event.getButton().getParent()).replaceComponent(event.getButton(), spinner);
            System.out.println("Yes?");

            getSaveListener().saveClick();

        }
```

Results into:

1. [image: Button]
2. *CLICK* =)
3. "SPINNER!"
4. "Yes?"
5. "Yes1"
6. "Waiting"
7. "Yes2"
8. [image: Spinning]

---

### Replace Component

The `.replaceComponent()` looks like this:

```
public void replaceComponent(Component oldComponent, Component newComponent) {

    // Gets the locations
    int oldLocation = -1;
    int newLocation = -1;
    int location = 0;
    for (final Iterator<Component> i = components.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        final Component component = i.next();

        if (component == oldComponent) {
            oldLocation = location;
        }
        if (component == newComponent) {
            newLocation = location;
        }

        location++;
    }

    if (oldLocation == -1) {
        addComponent(newComponent);
    } else if (newLocation == -1) {
        Alignment alignment = getComponentAlignment(oldComponent);
        float expandRatio = getExpandRatio(oldComponent);

        removeComponent(oldComponent);
        addComponent(newComponent, oldLocation);
        applyLayoutSettings(newComponent, alignment, expandRatio);
    } else {
        // Both old and new are in the layout
        if (oldLocation > newLocation) {
            components.remove(oldComponent);
            components.add(newLocation, oldComponent);
            components.remove(newComponent);
            components.add(oldLocation, newComponent);
        } else {
            components.remove(newComponent);
            components.add(oldLocation, newComponent);
            components.remove(oldComponent);
            components.add(newLocation, oldComponent);
        }

        markAsDirty();
    }
}
```

From the [API](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractOrderedLayout.html#replaceComponent%28com.vaadin.ui.Component,%20com.vaadin.ui.Component%29):

> replaceComponent
>
> - public void replaceComponent(Component oldComponent,
>                              Component newComponent)
>
> Replaces the component in the container with another one without changing position.
>
> This method replaces component with another one is such way that the new component overtakes the position of the old component. If the
>   old component is not in the container, the new component is added to
>   the container. If the both component are already in the container,
>   their positions are swapped. Component attach and detach events should
>   be taken care as with add and remove.
>
> - Specified by:
>
>   replaceComponent in interface ComponentContainer
>
> Parameters:
>
> - oldComponent: the old component that will be replaced.
> - newComponent: the new component to be replaced.

Comment: that save button looks cool.... From where did you get that?

Comment: @tharindu_DG Is pretty much the VAADIN valo-facebook "friendly" button with a FontAwesome icon. Also the spinner is the original VAADIN valo-facebook spinner: https://vaadin.com/valo

Comment: What is HorizontalLayout? Do you know details about the replaceComponent function?

Comment: What library are you using? Those images look like HTML maybe

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah it's a GWT framework called Vaadin. Didn't mention it cause it doesn't matter in that case (imho :P). http://www.gwtproject.org/

Comment: @JörnBuitink Here's the API: https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/HorizontalLayout.html

Comment: It may matter if the call to Thread.sleep blocks the images from redrawing. The code may just execute so fast, it looks out of order. I suggest throwing a print statement in the click listener before and after the call to the save listener to be sure it fires before the other one

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah, good thought... I'll test this and add it to the question.

Comment: @cricket_007 Ha! You were right. Check out my edit. Still not sure what it means though.

Comment: what GUI framework is this? Swing? Vaadin? GWT?

Comment: @OliverWatkins GWT and Vaadin (Vaadin is based on GWT).

Comment: @OliverWatkins Thanks... Nobody is looking at questions labeled with Vaadin -.- Another tumbleweed incoming YAY

Comment: it doesnt hurt to put both tags in :)

Comment: Means you should start a separate thread for the save listener actions

Comment: to me this looks like you are disregarding how vaadin works there.  the button click gets sent to the server.  the server then does _everything_ you ask in all the click handlers - but it just returns - when everything is done - the absolute last state, which the client later renders.  if you want to have such async behaviour you might want to enable polling while the calculation is done (the client polls the server every n ms for state changes) or you might want to investigate vaadin-push

Comment: why not using only one ClickListener? You can not influence the order of execution of listeners

Comment: @cfrick again, Your comment is the right answer. Can you post it? It's obvious that the UI is redrawed in browser once Vaadin finish handling the request. He needs to either enable push or polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cfrick pointed out, it is the normal Vaadin behavior that the client side UI will be updated once the listener execution has finished. In your example the listener executes a long running operation (the sleep). Once it is finished, the UI will be updated so that the last state is shown.

Vaadin docs have covered the topic: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-progressbar.html

There is a great example contained. The idea is to run the operation in a separate thread and update the UI via polling or Vaadin push.

P.S.: Since this question was already answered as comment by cfrick, I will provide it as community wiki.